# Is there a way to force new Windows OS to export as JPG instead of JFIF?

Tags: javascript, windows, image-processing, jpeg, jfif

I am trying to develop a site that exports images as JPGs and it works as expected but when doing cross browser testing, I noticed that browsers in new Windows OS computers download the files as JFIF.  I then came across several articles discussing this:

1. https://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-10-saving-jpgs-downloaded-from-the-internet-as-jfifs
2. https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1550/how-to-fix-the-error-of-saving-jpeg-images-into-jfif-on-google-chrome-for-windows-10

The solutions seem be registry changes the user would have to make. Does anyone know if there is a solution I can implement on the client that would force JPG over JFIF?

Comment: voting to close. this is not about programming. try https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This is a Windows bug/issue. As such, it's not something that a clientside script would have any control over.

The issue is a result of an incorrect file extension association (according to that Windows Club article you linked), which is not something you can override from the browser.